# NodeJS Express Req.Body is undefined

Tags: angularjs, node.js, ionic-framework, undefined

I have worked with several solutions posted on stack overflow, and I have yet to find one to work with me so I decided to ask.

Here is my nodejs file: (leaving out irrelevant code)

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var cors = require('cors');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(cors());

app.get('/sendEmail', function(req, res) {
 var answers = req.body.answers;
 console.log(answers);
})
```

and also my POST:

```js
$http.get('http://localhost:5000/sendEmail', {
  answers: answer
})
```

How come when I console log `req.body.answers` I get undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have a body in a `GET` request. So change this:

```
app.post('/sendEmail', function(req, res) {
    var answers = req.body.answers;
    // whatever
})
```

and this:

```
$http.post('http://localhost:5000/sendEmail', {
  answers: answer
})
```